# day elapsed use of progress bar in Qt?

Tags: qt, date, time, progress-bar

I want to show the percentage of day elapsed using the progress bar in Qt,
for example, if its 12pm it should show `12/24*100=50` on the progress bar.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a QTimer which calls slot `update()` every `n` minutes/hours:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000 * 60 * 60); // call update slot every hour
```

This slot then updates the value of the progressbar:

```
 QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
 progressBar->setValue(dateTime.time().hour()/24*100);
```